# Unable to animate just a frame to slide up on click of a button.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am try to create an animation in my app which would slide up a frame to my desired position. The frame would be having other buttons and text on it as well.

I was unable to use actionsheet for this, as it starts from the bottom most part of the window. What i want to create is shown in the picture below.

[image]

the frame I want to animate is the one with Capture mode: text.

Click on the button on the tabView I want this frame to slide up, starting from the top of the tabview. and again clicking the button should make the frame disappear.

So far my code looks like

```
-(IBAction)setting


{

    NSLog(@"finalShare Button");

    UIView *tempView;

    CGRect tmpFrame;

    tempView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 90)] 

                autorelease];

    [tempView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [tempView setAlpha:.87];

    tempView.hidden = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:tempView];



    tmpFrame = tempView.frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];

    tmpFrame.origin.y=390;

    self.view.frame=tmpFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

The problem I am facing here is that when I animate my frame to move, the main view moves along with it. Which is something I don't want it to do.

I am new to iPhone programming, please guide how can I fix this. 
Or what would be a better way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: change `self.view.frame=tmpFrame;` into your_view.frame

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make the view hidden, just add it as a subview after you set its frame to have y origin of 480. Also, don't use the old UIView animation methods; use blocks.

Here's an example of a view that starts with a y origin of 0. It gets positioned at negative y equal to its height, added as a subview then animated down to meet the keyboard coming up from the bottom of the screen.

```
// add to view while completely off-screen
CGRect unlockViewFrame = unlockView.frame;
unlockViewFrame.origin.y = -unlockViewFrame.size.height;
unlockView.frame = unlockViewFrame;

[self.view addSubview:unlockView];

unlockViewFrame.origin.y = 0.;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    unlockView.frame = unlockViewFrame;
}];
```

Here's the same thing in reverse, using a completion block to remove the view.

```
unlockViewFrame.origin.y = -unlockViewFrame.size.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    view.frame = unlockViewFrame;
} completion:^(BOOL completion) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Another thing I notice is that you are doing everything in code; consider doing it in Interface Builder. A smart man once told me that code you don't write can't have any bugs and he was right. It's easy to create a view in IB and instantiate it inyour code when you need it:

```
NSArray* nibViews;
nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UnlockView" owner:self options:nil];
UnlockView *unlockView = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
```

Also, consider using ARC. No more autorelease!

Answer (score 0):

Your resetting frame of main view and not tempView

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];

tmpFrame.origin.y=390;

tempView.frame=tmpFrame; //it should be tempView not self.view ie main view

[UIView commitAnimations];
```